# Error in Bio from "João de Barros" bot?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

In profile http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-377/joao-de-barros there is this bio (about):

> Pioneiro da gramática portuguesa. Publiquei a "Gramática da Língua Protuguesa" em 1540.

*Protuguesa* is wrong word? Or is it a joke?

---

No perfil http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-377/joao-de-barros aonde se encontra o "sobre" (about) do usuário (que é um bot):

> Pioneiro da gramática portuguesa. Publiquei a "Gramática da Língua Protuguesa" em 1540.

Acredito que *Protuguesa* esteja errado, seja uma palavra errada? Ou é uma brincadeira?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops... My bad.

I've corrected the typo. Thanks for calling it out!

I've also corrected it to use the original title, pointed out in [Américo Tavares' answer](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/error-in-bio-from-jo%C3%A3o-de-barros-bot/102#102).

Comment: The quotes is `Publiquei a "Gramática da Língua Protuguesa" em 1540` made me think it was deliberate.

Comment: No, I typed it myself, instead of copy-pasting the title, so I made a typo :P The quotes are there because I couldn't put the title in italics.

Answer (score 4):

It's a typo / É uma gralha (erro de digitação).

It should be / deve ser "Portuguesa".

By the way the original title is / A propósito o título original é  [Grammatica da lingua portuguesa](http://purl.pt/12148).

Comment: Sound like a joke.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento It's a possibility! But, since  most cases of swapping two letters, like "ro" instead of "or",  are just typos, I've assumed it was such a case.